# How can I output a string that can be copied to the Clipboard?

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard, messagebox

I am using a MessageBox to output a string that I want to be able to copy the text from and paste elsewhere. 
A MessageBox does not allow you to copy the text that it displays, so I need another option that would work.

I'm using:

```
MessageBox.Show("Test!");
```

Comment: Create own MessageBox with Form with TextBox. You can style textbox as a label, but still will be able to copy select and copy values.

Comment: You can actually do a `cntl-C` on a `MessageBox` and put the contents in to the clipboard. It does give you some extra text, but the content is there. Your code gives you `---------------------------

---------------------------
Test!
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
`.

Comment: Good question. Before displaying the message box you can set the text you are going to display in clipboard. You can use Clipboard.SetText("Test!"); and user can directly paste it using CTRL + V wherever he wants.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to let a User select and copy the Text from a TextBox, you could create your own Form with a TextBox inside and then show it, with  `.Show()` or `.ShowDialog()`.
The latter will present a `Modal` Form, as the Dialog created by `MessageBox.Show()`.

You can also create it *on the fly*; clicking on a Button, for example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowMyDialog("Dialog Title", "Test!");
}

private void ShowMyDialog(string title, string text)
{
    var form = new Form() {
        Text = title,
        Size = new Size(250, 80)
    };

    form.Controls.Add(new TextBox() {
        Font = this.Font,
        Text = text,
        Size = new Size(150, this.Font.Height),
        Location = new Point(50, 10)
    });

    form.ShowDialog();
    form.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().First().Dispose();
    form.Dispose();
}
```

If you instead want to put some text in the ClipBoard, you could use [ClipBoard.SetText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard.settext):

> Clears the Clipboard and then adds text data in the Text or
> UnicodeText format, depending on the operating system.

```
Clipboard.SetText("My String");
```

Then you can paste the string (where possible) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> or get it back in code with [Clipboard.GetText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard.gettext);

```
string fromClipBoard = Clipboard.GetText();
```

You can also specify a Text Format using the [TextDataFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textdataformat) enumerator:

```
Clipboard.SetText([HtmlContent], TextDataFormat.Html);
```